# Best way to disable validator control using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Can anyone tell me what is the best way to disable validator control using JavaScript?

Which one is the best way to dsiable validation control(considering compatability as well)?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

1]

```
var validatorObject = document.getElementById('<%=ValidatorControl.ClientID%>');
ValidatorEnable(validatorObject , true);
```

2]

```
var validatorObject = document.getElementById('<%=ValidatorControl.ClientID%>');
validatorObject.enabled = false;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call ValidatorEnable(val, enable) it calls a function that looks like this:
*(to see it open the `WebRescouce.axd` script)*

```
function ValidatorEnable(val, enable) {
    val.enabled = (enable != false);
    ValidatorValidate(val);
    ValidatorUpdateIsValid();
}
```

*By just enabling/disabling the validator(line 3), you can achieve what you want.*
Also, calling `ValidatorEnable` which further calls `ValidatorUpdateDisplay` will immediately validate the associated control and show any validation messages.

---

According to me rather than using multiple js calling better would be using

```
var validatorObject = document.getElementById('<%=ValidatorControl.ClientID%>');
validatorObject.enabled = false;
```

which simply serve's your purpose of enabling/disabling the validator...
[Reference Help](http://forums.asp.net/t/1175267.aspx?ValidatorEnable+Javascript+Function)

Comment: Thanks Bhavik, but I would like to know which one is the best way to disable validator control.